# Getting a blank popup in Windows 10 with no close button

Tags: windows-10, popups

I have been getting a blank popup on Windows 10 that doesn't have a close button. After it has been open for a long time, it gives some message that says "Cannot connect to..." but I cannot read the whole message and only then does the close button appear. How can I get rid of it? It has been a real headache so any help would be appreciated. I have attached the image as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the process that is the owner of an unknown window, download and install
[Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer).

Start Process Explorer and drag and drop its bull's-eye icon
([image])
over that window.

Process Explorer will position its window so the process is visible and selected.
To get more information, double-click the process to get its properties.
In the "Image" tab, especially, you will see the full path of the process,
which will further help in identifying its origin.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That fixed the issue!